# Why does str_split() add an extra layer of list?

Tags: r, stringr

Accessing tokens from a string seems overly complicated. There must be some unexplained concept I'm missing. I'd really appreciate understanding why `str_split()` works this way.

```
s = "hello world"
t = tokens = str_split(s, fixed(" "))
# attempts to get first token:

tokens[1]
# [[1]]
# [1] "hello" "world"

tokens[1][1]
# [[1]]
# [1] "hello" "world"

tokens[[1]]
# [1] "hello" "world"

tokens[[1]][1]
# [1] "hello"
```

I understand what it's doing. I just don't understand why it works that way. Other functions add an extra layer too sometimes. And it's a common source of frustration for me in R. An understanding of WHY may help me down the road.

Comment: Because it's vectorized, so it can do this too: `str_split(c("hello world","foo bar"),fixed(" "))`.

Comment: Yes, but many functions are vectorized that don't do that. For example, passing 1:99 to `function(a) {a+1}` would return a vector, not a list.

Comment: Right, but in this case the only sensible default is to return a list. If you flattened the results into a vector by default, and each piece split into a different number of pieces, it would be a real pain in the butt to figure out what came from which element of the original vector.

Answer (score 3):

You could always add `simplify = TRUE` to `str_split()`:

```
s = "hello world"
t = tokens = str_split(s, fixed(" "), simplify = TRUE)

tokens
#       [,1]    [,2]   
#  [1,] "hello" "world"

tokens[1]
# [1] "hello"

tokens[2]
# [2] "world"
```

Answer (score 2):

@semaphorism answer is correct (I upvoted it) but it doesn't answer the why question.All `stringr` functions are vectorised that's why they return a list where item one of the returned list is the result of applying the function to the first element of the vector input, this way you know what are the outputs for each element of the vectors. another workaround is to just unlist it:

```r
unlist(str_split(s, fixed(" ")))
```